# Is there any way to specify imports in the body of the file?

Tags: haskell

Essentially, is there any way to make this code legal?

```
main = print . sort $ [10, 1]
import Data.List
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't answer the question as it stands. Maybe you should edit your question (including, probably, the title) to reflect what it is you really want.

Comment: (although if you do that you should say what your question used to be, so the answer which answers it doesn't end up a non-sequitur)

Comment: As has already been pointed out, you want the `LINE` pragma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an answer to your comment on the purpose of this.

Prepend your imports separated by semi-colons, without a trailing line break like so.

```
import Data.List; main = print . sort $ [10, 1]
```

That way line numbers don't change.

Answer (score 1):

No. Imports must go [at the top](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1010005.3) of the module, before any code. The language definition says so. Only pragmas, the module header and comments can appear before the import declarations.

Comment: Ugh. I was hoping there was a ghc flag to handle this or something.

Comment: There isn't. Not yet at least. Why would you want that, by the way?

Comment: I'm writing an app where I have the user write Haskell code. I provide  an API for them in the form of some functions. To compile the final product, I concatenate the two files and compile it. So the final file looks like `bunch of imports \n bunch of my functions \n bunch of their functions`. If it doesn't compile, I output compilation errors. But since I append their code to mine, all the errors have incorrect line numbers. I could work around this by *prepending* their code to mine, except that now my imports wont work because they're not at the top.

Comment: I see. Can you post-process the compilation errors to adjust the line numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's what I will do. I was just hoping I wouldn't have to.

Comment: @VladtheImpala: You could also have a look at GHC's [LINE pragma](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#line-pragma), that seems like it could help you out.

Comment: @yatima2975 you should submit that as an answer! That's the best option I've seen so far.